# save method not working in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, async-await

I am using the following code in node.js:

```
async function create(data) {
    utils.removeIdFields(data);
    const user = new User(data);
    console.log("user will be printed here", user);
    await user.save();
    console.log("code not reaching here");
    return user;
}
```

In the above code, User is a mongoose model, which is working fine till the line above user.save(). However, it never prints the next log.

I am using mongoose version 4.11.0.

Comment: can you please show me the model?

Comment: make sure you are adding the line to your model:
 `mongoose.Promise = Promise;`

Comment: yup, this is tried this, still doesn't work.. @HaroonKhan

Comment: @KshitijMittal Same! Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was connecting to MongoDB using the following piece of code:

```
function connectMongoDb() {
    if (mongoose.connect(makeMongoUrl(), { useMongoClient: true })) {
        mongoose.plugin(plugins.transformer);
    }
}
```

As it turned out, removing the { useMongoClient: true } and using just the below code fixed the issue:

```
function connectMongoDb() {
    if (mongoose.connect(makeMongoUrl())) {
        mongoose.plugin(plugins.transformer);
    }
}
```